# Using Java to retrieve web page contents does not match what a screen copy gets me

Tags: java, httprequest

When I run the following code it prints out the contents of the given page.
However when I do a select all and copy of the actual page manually I get different text. What must I do so that when I run the java request that I will get the same text as when I to a ctrl+a, ctrl+c

```
        URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20131204/");
    URLConnection yc = myUrl.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
```

Comment: Where is the difference?

Comment: As Adam said, Post the difference will give us way to help

Comment: Try to set the enconding to the InputStreamReader, BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your code you get the HTML source of the page.

When you show the page in a browser and visually select and copy the page contents (ctrl-a, ctrl-c) you get a copy of the content rendered by a browser.

If you want to access the contents of the page programmatically you need to parse it somehow; JSoup library would be a good choice to select specific contents. HTMLUnit is a non-visual browser library that renders the page and lets you work with the result; this is closer to your current approach.

(Assuming you are not ctrl-a, ctrl-c in a source window, of course.)

Comment: This is defo the problem,  now to go check out this HTMLunit library,  cheers

Answer (score 1):

This could depend on various reasons. For example:

- browser can do some non-visual for user conversation with server, receiving cookies from it and sending them again
- page can be modified dynamically with javascript
- page contents can be modified on server depeneding on browser's name from headers of request

and so.

Comment: @Andremniy did you have a preview on my answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy job! Following reasons why you get different results:

- Server delivers different pages depending on the browser (technically it's the HTTP header 'User-Agent' which often controls logic on server-side)
- AJAX requests change the page content
- Client-side logic (e.g. Modernizr) controls the output variants

Don't know whether there is some kind of binding for Java, but a possible solution would be to use [PhantomJS](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/).

BTW with your Java code you're eating the new-line/curriage-return characters, because BufferedReader.readLine() strips off the `\n`.